# CSS3 Drop down full width

Tags: css, drop-down-menu

I'm trying to make a css3 drop down menu that covers the whole width of my page. I've tried to edit the current code but without any good results.

If I edit the ul,li and set width to 20%, then only the hover button changes to that size. It seems like half of the active button is not showing. I've been fiddling around for a long time now and I'm getting pretty frustrated as all my attempts result in nothing.

Could anyone please help me or give me some advice? It would be very much appreciated so please don't be shy to help a beginner in need!

Have a nice day.

sorry forgot to put the fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/dennis2society/hEGut/

HTML:

```
<div id='cssmenu'>
<ul>
<li class='active'><a href='index.html'>Home</a>
</li>
<li><a href='#'>Training</a>
<ul>
<li><a href='#'>Pupils</a>
</li>
<li><a href='#'>Juniors</a>
</li>
<li><a href='#'>Seniors</a>
</li>
</ul>
</li>
<li><a href='#'>Competition</a>
<ul>
<li><a href='#'>Pupils</a>
</li>
<li><a href='#'>Juniors</a>
</li>
<li><a href='#'>Seniors</a>
</li>
</ul>
</li>
<li><a href='#'>About Us</a>
</li>
<li><a href='#'>Contact</a>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#cssmenu ul, #cssmenu li, #cssmenu span, #cssmenu a {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
position: relative;
}
#cssmenu:after, #cssmenu ul:after {
content:'';
display: block;
clear: both;
}
#cssmenu a {
color: #ffffff;
display: inline-block;
font-family: Helvetica, Arial, Verdana, sans-serif;
font-size: 12px;
min-width: 35px;
text-align: center;
text-decoration: none;
text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 #333333;
}
#cssmenu ul {
list-style: none;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li {
float: left;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li.active a {
background: #646464 url(images/grad_dark.png) repeat-x left bottom;
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #646464 0%, #4a4a4a 100%);
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #646464), color-stop(100%, #4a4a4a));
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #646464 0%, #4a4a4a 100%);
background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #646464 0%, #4a4a4a 100%);
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #646464 0%, #4a4a4a 100%);
background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #646464 0%, #4a4a4a 100%);
filter: progid:dximagetransform.microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#646464', endColorstr='#4a4a4a', GradientType=0);
box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px #222222, inset 0 10px 10px #222222;
-moz-box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px #222222, inset 0 10px 10px #222222;
-webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px #222222, inset 0 10px 10px #222222;
filter: none;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li.active a:hover {
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #646464 0%, #4a4a4a 100%);
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #646464), color-stop(100%, #4a4a4a));
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #646464 0%, #4a4a4a 100%);
background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #646464 0%, #4a4a4a 100%);
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #646464 0%, #4a4a4a 100%);
background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #646464 0%, #4a4a4a 100%);
filter: progid:dximagetransform.microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#646464', endColorstr='#4a4a4a', GradientType=0);
filter: none;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li a {
box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1px #8a8a8a;
-moz-box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1px #8a8a8a;
-webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1px #8a8a8a;
background: #4a4a4a url(images/grad_dark.png) repeat-x left top;
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #8a8a8a 0%, #707070 50%, #626262 51%, #787878 100%);
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #8a8a8a), color-stop(50%, #707070), color-stop(51%, #626262), color-stop(100%, #787878));
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #8a8a8a 0%, #707070 50%, #626262 51%, #787878 100%);
background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #8a8a8a 0%, #707070 50%, #626262 51%, #787878 100%);
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #8a8a8a 0%, #707070 50%, #626262 51%, #787878 100%);
background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #8a8a8a 0%, #707070 50%, #626262 51%, #787878 100%);
filter: progid:dximagetransform.microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#8a8a8a', endColorstr='#787878', GradientType=0);
border-bottom: 1px solid #5d5d5d;
border-top: 1px solid #5d5d5d;
border-right: 1px solid #5d5d5d;
line-height: 34px;
padding: 0 35px;
filter: none;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li a:hover {
background: #8a8a8a url(images/grad_dark.png) repeat-x left bottom;
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #646464 0%, #4a4a4a 50%, #3b3b3b 51%, #525252 100%);
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #646464), color-stop(50%, #4a4a4a), color-stop(51%, #3b3b3b), color-stop(100%, #525252));
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #646464 0%, #4a4a4a 50%, #3b3b3b 51%, #525252 100%);
background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #646464 0%, #4a4a4a 50%, #3b3b3b 51%, #525252 100%);
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #646464 0%, #4a4a4a 50%, #3b3b3b 51%, #525252 100%);
background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #646464 0%, #4a4a4a 50%, #3b3b3b 51%, #525252 100%);
filter: progid:dximagetransform.microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#8a8a8a', endColorstr='#787878', GradientType=0);
filter: none;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li:first-child a {
border-left: 1px solid #5d5d5d;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li:last-child a {
}
#cssmenu li:hover ul {
display: block;
}
#cssmenu li ul {
display: none;
position: absolute;
top: 36px;
left: -1px;
min-width: 100%;
text-align: center;
/* IE7 */
*width: 100%;
}
#cssmenu li ul li {
text-align: center;
}
#cssmenu li ul li a {
border-top: 0 none;
border-left: 1px solid #5d5d5d;
display: block;
line-height: 120%;
padding: 9px 5px;
text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were almost there, all you need is a width declaration on the first level `li` and a `display:block` and their child anchor elements:

```
#cssmenu > ul > li {
             /* width here:*/
    float: left;width:20%;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li a {
    display:block;
    /* the other stuff*/
}
```

[Your modified fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hEGut/1/)

p.s. nice design! However, you should check it with several different browsers, there is some difference between Chome and Firefox/IE.

Comment: I forgot about the display element, thanks for that!

I have noticed the slight change in the borders on the buttons in IE (#11), it's not major but if there is a quick fix I would like to know about it if possible.
If it's a fix that completely turns the current code upside down then I think it's best to leave it as is. Unless you really want to help me to get the nav to a perfect standard. Thanks for your effort, you are a life saver :)